# microsoft graph api to create online meeting programmatically but facing 403 error

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using Microsoft Graph Api (PHP->msGraph SDK) to create online meetings.
I'm Facing 403 error can someone help me out.

```
$clientId = "***********************************";
$clientSecret = "***********************************";
$tenantId = '***********************************';
$responseUri = "http://localhost:8888/moodle39";



$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;

//Create a new Graph client. 
$graph = new Graph(); 
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$onlinemeet->startDateTime = "2020-09-02T14:30:34.2444915";
$onlinemeet->endDateTime = "2020-09-02T15:30:34.2444915";
$onlinemeet->subject = "Test Meeting";
$jso = json_encode($onlinemeet);
$user = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/onlineMeetings")->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))->attachBody($jso)->setReturnType(User::class) ->execute();
```

**Exception - Client error: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: { "error": { "code": "Forbidden", "message": "", "innerError": { "request-id": "bd43aa57-511e-4 (truncated...)**

While creating an application in azure portal

under API permission i gave permission to access

> GraphApi->Delegated Permissions->onlinemeetings.ReadWrite.

Can someone help me with a proper example or proper syntax in PHP.

Thankyou !!..

Comment: I don't see you adding any credentials to your quest in your code.

Comment: checkout the question. I just edited the question with full code.
Thank you @ewong !!

Comment: After seeing the code I got to know that you are using the client crediential flow and calling the 'me/onlineMeetings' endpoint. Basically When authenticating as an application, you can't use delegated permissions - scopes that are granted by a user. So you should be using Application permissions here. And as we see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) the Application permissions are not supported here. So that's the reason you are getting 403 error.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity
Thanks for your reply
Yes, I'm using delegated permissions, If you see the documentation which you shared to me. Delegated (work or school account) OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite Supports.
If my account is a personal account then it doesn't work.
But mine was a work account so delegated permissions are supported

Comment: @sreenumalae After running this code did it asked you for the work or school account credientials? And are you following any public sample? if so please share the link.

Comment: You are not using delegated auth. The line `'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',` indicates you are using app-only auth. You need to do a user auth flow here, like authentication code. There's a tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/tutorials/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token to call the **/me** endpoint. For the client credential flow, it is usually used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background and do not interact with the user immediately(No user logged in). For the **/me** endpoint, it is usually User login is required, so you should use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

By the way, APIs under the **/beta** version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported. Therefore, it is recommended that you use the **/v1.0** version.

[image]

please see:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

---

**Update:**

There are many similar samples, I hope they can help you:

[OAuth 2.0 PHP Sample Code](https://developer.byu.edu/docs/consume-api/use-api/oauth-20/oauth-20-php-sample-code).

[Authentication and Authorization Using Auth0 in PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-and-authorization-using-auth0-in-php--cms-31134).

Comment: Can you please provide a php example (Not Laravel) for auth code flow.
It will be more helpful.

Comment: @sreenumalae   Hi, I updated the answer, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).  This can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Hello, Your answer helped me a lot. In my code, once the user logged in I will get a code using that I'm getting an access token.
with that, I'm trying to create a meeting but I'm getting an error 
Exception - Class 'User' not found
ine 156 of /mod/certificate/vendor/microsoft/microsoft-graph/src/Http/GraphResponse.php: Error thrown
line 291 of /mod/certificate/vendor/microsoft/microsoft-graph/src/Http/GraphRequest.php: call to Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse->getResponseAsObject()
line 128 of /mod/certificate/view.php: call to Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphRequest->execute()

Comment: @sreenumalae  Hi, I have no way to answer you in the comment, because I need you to provide your code to facilitate my testing. Can you accept this answer first and then ask a new question? Attach your code and error message, I will answer for you as soon as possible.

Comment: i resolved the issue thankyou so much for your quick response.